# How to set height borderlayout ZK automaticly fit to parent size

Tags: java, zk

a question to be answered why `borderlayout` set `height="100%"` not working but when i set height using pixels it's working fine,i am try to adding `vflex="1"` but still nothing happen,how to make it fit to parent size automaticly? this is my zul code :

```
<zk xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul">
    <window border="none" width="90%" height="min"
            apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" 
            viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.dp.acction.adira.bitozen.interfaces.web.ui.viewmodel.CetakMainVM')">
        <!--    SUB-SUB -->        
    <borderlayout height="100%">
        <center>
            <borderlayout>
                <west  size="25%" collapsible="true">
                    <div style="background:#B8D335">
                        <label value="Test layout" />
                    </div>
                </west>
            <center>
                <div>
                     <vlayout>
                        <groupbox  width="100%"  visible="true">
                                     <caption label="${labels.common.label.hasil_pencarian}"
                                     style="color:blue" />
                                     <vlayout hflex="1" width="80%">
                                         <checkbox  name="chkBPKB" label="Print SPP/SIP BPKB" checked="@bind(vm.chkBPKB)" />
                                         <listbox model="@load(vm.poDTOs)" 
                                          mold="paging" 
                                          pageSize="10"
                                          height="50%"
                                          emptyMessage="Tidak ada data" 
                                          checkmark="true"
                                          width="100%"          
                                          selectedItem="@bind(vm.aksiSelectedPO)"
                                          onClick="@command('onCheckRadio')"  style="overflow:hidden">
                                             <listhead  >
                                                  <listheader  label="${labels.common.label.pilih}" width="50px" align="center"/>
                                                  <listheader label="${labels.common.label.sentra}" width="150px" align="center"/>
                                                  <listheader label="${labels.common.label.unit}" width="150px" align="center"/>
                                                  <listheader label="${labels.common.label.jenis_pihak_ketiga}" width="150px" align="center"/>
                                                  <listheader label="${labels.common.label.nama_pihak_ketiga}" width="150px" align="center"/>
                                                  <listheader label="${labels.common.label.no_po}" width="150px" align="center"/>
                                                  <listheader label="${labels.common.label.nama_lengkap}" width="150px" align="center"/>
                                                  <listheader label="${labels.common.label.no_aplikasi}" width="150px" align="center"/>
                                              </listhead>
                                              <template name="model"  status="s" var="item">
                                         <listitem>  
                                             <listcell />
                                             <listcell label="@load(item.sentraID)" />
                                             <listcell label="@load(item.unitID)" />
                                             <listcell label="@load(item.thirdPartyTypeID)" />
                                             <listcell label="@load(item.thirdPartyName)" /> 
                                             <listcell label="@load(item.poNumber)" /> 
                                             <listcell label="@load(item.customerName)" /> 
                                             <listcell label="@load(item.orderID)" /> 
                                         </listitem>                                          
                                         </template> 
                                         </listbox>
                                     </vlayout>
                                 </groupbox>     
                     </vlayout>
                </div>
            </center>
            </borderlayout>
        </center>    
    </borderlayout>
    </window>
</zk>
```

when i am searching about this i found this  [thread in zk forum](http://forum.zkoss.org/question/42210/borderlayout-height100-failed-on-opera-and-ie-with-zk5/?sort=oldest&page=1#sort-top) but still no getting solution.

Comment: Please, in the future, post smaller examples. Whoever find the time to look at all that zul stuff won't be able to run it immediately. We have to remove the composer, the viewmodel, all the bindings... Then it complains that the groupbox cannot have width and hflex set at the same time (which produces an error in zk 8, and works unreliably before already). Throw away everything you don't need to produce the error you are asking us about: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i am sorry to many code in my question, after i am reading in the link above i will try to post better question in the future and following the rule.

Answer (score 0):

First issue: why do you set the window's heigth to "min"? This is an invalid value. The rendered html component's element style will be ignored by the browser. The window will be as high as necessary for the content.

And that is the problem: Your border layout says "parent, how much space do you have for me, I take what you can give me" (height: 100%). So the end result is that the window will have 0 height because none of its children demand any fixed height.

Read about this exact problem in the [zk documentation](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Patterns/Hflex_and_Vflex#Parent_Requires_Width.2FHeight).

So there are 2 solutions:

- Set your window's height to 100% or 90% or 500px or anyhting but min and it'll work. I tried 100% with your code, and it shows just fine. This way, the window will be in charge of determining the height. It takes the whole browser window, and the border layout will fill 100%.
- If you want the content (listbox) decide the size of the window, use `vflex="min"` on all parents of the listbox (window until inner vlayout) This way, your parents will ask their children how much space they need. This will be delegated down to the listbox, which is sized by its rows, or absolute height, or `rows` attribute. (Do **not** use flexible height for the listbox then, otherwise you have the problem again that nobody wants to decide the height, and everything either collapse to 0 or expands to full height.)

Comment: i've change my window height to 100% and i set height the first and the second borderlayout to 100% but still same result , i am using zk version 7.0.5 is it the zk problem or no?

Answer (score 0):

I use the style attribute to solve my autofit problem with components in div, borderlayout, etc.

```
<listbox vflex="max" style="height: calc(100%)" width="100%">
```

Comment: i've trying but still not working, maybe it's not posible to use height="100%" in zk borderlayout